# NotSerializableException when using Slick images

Tags: java, image, networking, serialization

I've recently started adding networking into my game, and this is the first time i've had experience with anything like this.

I'm using this Slick API to handle my graphics (among some other things) and using ObjectInputSteams and ObjectOutputStreams to do the networking.

I decided to test the connection by sending an image through the server, and was met with a NotSerializableException for the image:

```
    java.io.WriteAbortedException: writing aborted; java.io.NotSerializableException:     org.newdawn.slick.Image
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1332)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:350)
at inGame.ConnectClient.alwaysGet(ConnectClient.java:50)
at inGame.ConnectClient.setUp(ConnectClient.java:26)
at inGame.ConnectClient.run(ConnectClient.java:34)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:680)
    Caused by: java.io.NotSerializableException: org.newdawn.slick.Image
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1164)
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:330)
at inGame.ConnectServer.write(ConnectServer.java:40)
at scenes.HostMenu.update(HostMenu.java:47)
at org.newdawn.slick.state.StateBasedGame.update(StateBasedGame.java:268)
at org.newdawn.slick.GameContainer.updateAndRender(GameContainer.java:657)
at org.newdawn.slick.AppGameContainer.gameLoop(AppGameContainer.java:408)
at org.newdawn.slick.AppGameContainer.start(AppGameContainer.java:318)
at scenes.Head.main(Head.java:47)
```

How would i make the object serializable? Or am i going in the complete wrong direction with all of this?

Any input is appreciated!

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One easy way to make third-party class Serializable is to make your own class that extends Image class and implements java.io.Serializable interface (remember to prepare all versions of constructor and delegate them to the base class' constructor).

However Slick's Image class may be not-Serializable for a good reason. If it contains some low-level, operating system related stuff, it may be impossible to just serialize it, send it to the server and open there. Maybe some simplier solutions like just sending image name to the server and loading it from a file on server would be more reliable?

Answer (score 0):

You're using `ObjectInputStream / ObjectOutputStream` to send object to remote client. You can send in that way only objects, which are **serializable**, t.m. they implement `java.io.Serializable` interface and all their **non-transient** fields are primitive values **or** implement `java.io.Serializable`.

First solution: make all your objects serializable. This will not work, however, if you use thirt-party objects which are not serializable.

Second solution: use other serialization that java-build-in. For example, you can use **[XStream](http://xstream.codehaus.org/)**, very robust Java serialization/deserialization library.

Third solution: XML serialization is not the best way to send binary data, such as images. In that case you need to handle serialization and deserialization itself. You'll open simple output/input stream and write/read there binary data.